# Typescript error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map' in aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. `mkdir` and `cd` into it..
2. `npm init` and accept the defaults
3. `jspm init`.. accept defaults except don't use a transpiler
4. `jspm install aurelia-framework`
5. `jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper`
6. Add an empty `tsconfig.json` file to the directory.. I've tried many tsconfig settings to fix this problem, but it works just the same with a simple `{ }` configuration. I've even tried various mutations of https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-typescript-asp.net5/src/skeleton-navigation-typescript-vs/tsconfig.json to no avail.
7. `tsc`

At this point, you should stumble across the errors: 

`jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6/aurelia-binding.d.ts(331,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.6/aurelia-binding.d.ts(353,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.`

I'm guessing a dependency is missing?

In this repro, you'll also see some TS2304 errors in other aurelia*.d.ts files, but I'm not actually seeing those in my actual environment for some reason.

I've tried type adding the typings.json file from https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-typescript-asp.net5/src/skeleton-navigation-typescript-vs/typings.json and then issued `typings install`, but that didn't change anything. Oddly enough, it didn't even help if I tried `typings install es6-promise --save'.

No matter what I try, I always get the same errors when I run `tsc`

For the record, I'm running the following versions...

- npm v3.9.0
- jspm v0.16.34
- tsc v1.8.10

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Target ES6 in your tsconfig compiler options or add the d.ts files for ES6 collections

Comment: Just wanted to say "Hey Alex!" missed ya!

Comment: @JeremyDanyow for the win.

Comment: @basarat for the awesome.

Comment: Also, @JeremyDanyow, post an answer and I'll award it to you. Can you give any tips for what I might have binged to discover that answer on my own? I spent a fair amount of time trying to figure it out on my own, but it seems like your solution came so easily. I'm wondering if maybe I have a knowledge gap somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new `--lib` option `--lib es6` to just use the lib file for ES6 and still keep your compile target to be ES5.

## More

More on `lib` option : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6974

(PS: its supported in alm https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/)